# how do I share an app intent via link in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making a recipe app in android (java) and I want to have the ability to share a recipe with a friend via link. I do not own a domain, and my DB is local.

Is there a way to encode my data to a URL so the other device will know to open it in my app and get the information it needs?

Comment: I'm not sure but if you implement facebook share somehow to your app?Check this[link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/componentsdks)

Comment: Is [this](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) what you're looking for?

Comment: @lucidbrot thank you!